# Extensión archivo Sqlite con Python flask_sqlalchemy: ¿debe terminar el fichero en ".db"?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite3, sqlalchemy

Estoy testando la extensión `flask_sqlalchemy` con `sqlite3` como engine.

- En principio había nombrado mi archivo de banco de datos como `data.sqlite`, inclusive porque ya había visto en algún tutorial un nombre parecido con esa extensión.
- Cuando llamaba el método `create_all()`, el archivo era creado, pero no las tablas.
- Cambié la extensión del archivo para `data.db` y ahí sí, las tablas fueron creadas correctamente.

No encontré información en la documentación de sqlite respecto a que hubiese alguna restricción en este sentido, aparentemente `data.sqlite` sería un nombre válido.

¿Alguien sabe si esto es así realmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no me consta que sea necesario que la BBDD se llame ***.db**. De hecho, te adjunto un código que, aunque poco ortodoxo, demuestra que se puede usar el nombre **db.sqlite**.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///db.sqlite"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ItemModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "items"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))


db.create_all()
db.session.commit()

item = ItemModel(id=1, name='mi primer item')
db.session.add(item)
db.session.commit()
items = ItemModel.query.all()

print(items)
```